# Como aumentar o timeout no IIS 7,5

Tags: windows, iis, web.config, iis-7

Olá,
estou com problemas na execução de uma funcionalidade que roda no MVC3 em um servidor IIS 7,5. Como a funcionalidade retorna muitas linhas, após 30 segundos de execução, ela simplesmente aborta, já tentei várias configurações, mas não consegui uma que resolvesse.

Esta é a configuração do app pool.
[image: Imagem do app Pool]

Mas a configuração que preciso não, é o tempo ocioso, e sim o tempo de execução que preciso aumentar.

Grato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente este código no web config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="200" />
</system.web>
```

Obs:
Vi esse post de um problema parecido no Stack Overflow em inglês e a resposta acima: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214127/php-maximum-execution-time-exceeded-iis-overriding

Edit:

Se por acaso não resolver, seria interessante você habilitar o log do IIS. Segue o link para configurar:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82a82953-ab93-44a5-8c20-d5ddf2563179